# Cleveref equation instead of eq

Tags: equations, cross-referencing, cleveref

I use the `cleveref` package for referencing equations, among other things.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{equation1}
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

A reference to \cref{equation1}.

\end{document}
```

This comes out as:

"A reference to eq. (1)".

How could I adjust my code, so that it comes out as:

"A reference to equation (1)"?

Many thanks.

Comment: Use the package option `noabbrev` like `\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
` instead of `\usepackage{cleveref}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the package option `noabbrev` like `\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}`
 instead of `\usepackage{cleveref}`.

Just in case you are writing in German you could also use the command `\Cref{}` (with a capital C). Note that its output is always capitalized as it is intended to be used at the beginning of a sentence.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:equation1}
1 + 1 = 2.
\end{equation}

A reference to \cref{eq:equation1}.

\end{document}
```

Output
[image]

Comment: If you use babel, it's translations should (?) take care of required capitalization.